# Questions about Android Studio and HAXM Installation

Tags: android

I am a student majoring in computer engineering.
I downloaded 'Android Studio' to take an Android programming course, but it wasn't installed properly like the picture.
[android studio install fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoITK.jpg)
So I found the same error as this picture during HAXM download and installation.
[HAXM's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXHnr.jpg)
There are a total of four issues with VMX support, VMX support, EPT support, and Hyper-V disablement. When I searched several places, MS said it could run commands on Windows PowerShell, but it didn't work because of lack of privileges. I also looked up Control Panel - Program features, but there was no Hyper-V folder. There was a program like VMware, but it was deleted from the control panel. (CPU is using Intel just in case.) I need your help. I'm sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you've already installed HAXM wich enables the virtulization in Android Studio. But this HAXM needs to work with the machine's virtualization system which is found in the BIOS of each machine, In some machines it comes disabled.
All you need to do is restart the computer and open the BIOS settings. Then from there, search all tabs and look for the virtualization checkbox and check (enable it).
After you lauch again Android Studio.... It should work now.

Comment: I've been to the BIOS, but I couldn't because I couldn't see anything related to the virtualization system. XD

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.